# Android UI design

Tags: android, user-interface

I wanted some resources to learn how to design for android ?

What are the dimensions we need to have ?

Can we have custom dialog and alert box design ?

Can you guide me to some resources like articles or books etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some helpful links:

To learn about different layout types. Personally I recommend RelativeLayout.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html

As for dimensions: [What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

As for custom dialogs: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application

Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

checkout this site http://www.androidpatterns.com/ .This has got guidelines for common UI design patterns

Answer (score 5):

The Wrox book is a good one for getting to know how to make applications and make full use of the functionalities of the android UI design.

http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Android-2-Application-Development.productCd-0470565527.html

There is this online tutorial also it has lot of functionalities with examples

http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html

I would like to what exactly you are targeting at

Yes you can create custom dialogs and alert boxes in android

Answer (score 4):

> I wanted some resources to learn how to design for android ?

The website [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/) is your friend.

> What are the dimensions we need to have ?

Android comes in all sorts of form factors, so you should design your UI in a way that it can be scaled to any form factor. (So, for example, you shouldn't use absolute positioning  or absolute dimensions).

> Can we have custom dialog and alert box design ?

Yes, you can use custom UI elements. However, it is often a good idea to reuse standard UI elements in order to present the user with something that they are already accustomed to using.